# Audio On-end Play New File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5-audio

I have a [webapp](https://radio.repjesus.com) that loads and plays audio tracks when you click on a link using ajax/jquery. Everything works fine, but when the track ends, the track is set to loop and this can go on forever. I would like the player to autoload a random track from the database and play when one track ends. The audio is setup as such.

```
<div id="player"><audio title="Audio title" controls loop autoplay controlsList="nodownload" preload="auto" id="myAudio" /><source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mp3" id="audioID"></div>
```

Am using jquery to load a new track into the #player div when you click on it. eg;

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="loadurl('player.php?play=audioID','player')">Track One</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

<!-- ajaxified -->
function loadurl(dest, targetID) {
    
var XMLHttpRequestObject = false; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
            XMLHttpRequestObject = new 
            ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp"); 
    } 

if(XMLHttpRequestObject) { 
            XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dest); 
            XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && 
            XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) { 
            document.getElementById(targetID).innerHTML = 
            XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText; 
            delete XMLHttpRequestObject; 
            XMLHttpRequestObject = null; 
            } 
        } 
        XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null); 
    } 
} 

</script>
```

In my player.php file I have;

```
<?php  
.... fetch track from db where id = $_GET['play']; ......
?>

<audio title="Audio Title" controls loop autoplay controlsList="nodownload" preload="auto" id="myAudio" /> 
<source src="audio2.mp3" type="audio/mp3" id="audioID">
```

I've tried several suggestions from here and online like adding;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const audio = document.querySelector('myAudio');

audio.onended = (event) => {
  console.log('Video stopped either because 1) it was over, ' +
      'or 2) no further data is available.');
};

</script>
```

and this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const audio = document.querySelector('myAudio');

audio.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
  console.log('Video stopped either because 1) it was over, ' +
      'or 2) no further data is available.');
});

</script>
```

and this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
myAudio.addEventListener("ended", function(){
     myAudio.currentTime = 0;
     console.log("ended");
     alert("ended");
});

</script>
```

But none of them work. What am I doing wrong?

***UPDATE***

Thanks to contributions by @Roko C. Buljan I was able to use the following script to load a new track into the div#player. When track ends, a click is simulated using the ajax function loadurl and a new track is loaded into #player. This loads a new track but when that track ends, it won't load another track. How can I fix that?

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="randomplay" onClick="loadurl('player.php?random=1','player')"></a>
<script type="text/javascript">

const audio = document.querySelector('#myAudio');

audio.addEventListener("ended", () => {

        $("#randomplay").click();

    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: PS... STOP using `on*` inline JS handlers. JS (same as STYLE) should be all in their respective tags or files. Use `addEventListener` instead. Also  `text/javascript` isn’t required in `<script>` tag as of HTML5.

Comment: Also, should be `document.querySelector('#myAudio');` not `document.querySelector('myAudio');`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan hey bro! So I got it to work to an extent but I am not able to get it to load the next track. Any ideas? Am using ajax to load an php page into a div but after loading the next track, it can't loading again.

Answer (score 0):

***Tl;Dr:*** Use: `audio.addEventListener("ended", playNextFn);`

There's two possibilities:

#### 1. If the client has not a complete list of tracks:

Create a route on your server that can respond with a random track and send it back via AJAX to the client as JSON like `{"src": "bazzz.mp3", "name": "", "group": "", "year": "", "cover": ""}`.

```js
const audio = new Audio(); // or: document.querySelector('#myAudio');

const playRandomFile = () => {
  fetch("/api/getRandomSong.php").then(res => res.json).then(data => {
    audio.src = data.src;
    audio.play();
  });
};

audio.addEventListener("ended", playRandomFile); // ♫♪♫...♪♫♪♫♪...♫♪!
```

Hopefully you know how to write a PHP code that gets a random entry from a database `songs` table and return it as JSON.

#### 2. If the client knows upfront all the tracks:

Use JS to switch to a random track on `"ended"` Event.

```
const songs = [
  {src: "xyz.mp3", name: "", group: "", year:"", cover: ""},
  {src: "foo.mp3", name: "", group: "", year:"", cover: ""},
  {src: "bar.mp3", name: "", group: "", year:"", cover: ""},
];

const audio = new Audio(); // or: document.querySelector('#myAudio');

const playRandomFile = () => {
  audio.src = songs[~~(Math.random() * songs.length)].src;
  audio.play();
};

audio.addEventListener("ended", playRandomFile); // ♫♪♫...♪♫♪♫♪...♫♪!
```

Tip-of-the-day: you can generate your HTML in JS right out of the `songs` array.

#### Full Example

with Wikimedia audio files and a HTML `<audio>` Element:

```js
const songs = [
  {src: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg", name: "", group: "", year:"", cover: ""},
  {src: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/39/Metallica_-_Enter_Sandman.ogg", name: "", group: "", year:"", cover: ""},
  {src: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/U2_One.ogg", name: "", group: "", year:"", cover: ""},
];

const audio = document.querySelector('#myAudio');
const getRandomSong = () => songs[~~(Math.random() * songs.length)];

audio.addEventListener("ended", () => {
  audio.src = getRandomSong().src
  audio.play()
}); 

audio.src = getRandomSong().src // on DOM ready
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" controls></audio>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but would this mean all the songs will have to be listed first right? If the db has over 1000 songs, all these would have to be listed and then randomly selects one? Is there a way to just fetch one song from the db at the end of the track instead?

Comment: @JaySmoke Yes, in such case you need a PHP route like i.e: /api/getRandomSong.php that responds with a JSON like `{file: "bazzz.mp3", name: "", group: "", year:"", cover: ""}` and from there on you simply load it into the audio Object  like in the `playRandomFile` function example. How to use JS `fetch`... well, hope you can google for it! Otherwise I can give you a quick example if you find it too hard.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got the error Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. I guess I will need that quick JS Fetch example when we get there :)

Comment: @JaySmoke added an example and fixed the other.

Comment: am trying with the second option but nothing happens when track ends. Am not sure it's detecting the audio.

Comment: @JaySmoke are you sure `audio.src` is pointing to the right directory? I used `audio.src = xy.mp3` as an example, you as a developer should know if your songs are actually inside `audio.src = /files/audio/mp3s/rock/xy.mp3` or whatever... and act accordingly.

Comment: and when I use document.querySelector('#myAudio'); I get the error uncaught ReferenceError: audio is not define. I don't see where you used audio.src = xyz.mp3. Are you referring to the file: "xyz.mp3" if so then yes, I changed all that to the full path to the audio file.

Comment: @JaySmoke added a third full example with real songs.

Comment: Now, since `~~(Math.random() * songs.length)` could casually give again the same index, and replay the same song... it's your job as an engineer to make sure you'll not play the same song again. That's a task/homework for the reader.

Comment: Awesome it's working with on main page but it's not working with the ajax loaded file.

Comment: @JaySmoke I'm sure you'll find where's the issue :) perhaps you're not returning a valid JSON - cannot say. Use `echo`, in PHP, `console.log` in JS. And you'll be there in no-time :)