# Ajax HTML5 Audio Player can't load next track after second track plays

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, audio, html5-audio

This is a follow-up question to this post...

[Auto load new song into HTML 5 audio player when track ends using php/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69470533/auto-load-new-song-into-html-5-audio-player-when-track-ends-using-php-jquery)

Thanks to contributions by @Roko C. Buljan I was able to use the following script to load a new track into the div#player. When track ends, I simulated a click using the ajax function loadurl which then loads a new track into div#player. This plays alright and it's suppose to load a new track when it ends and on and on, but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

const audio = document.querySelector('#myAudio');

audio.addEventListener("ended", () => {

        loadurl.call(this,'player.php?random=1','player');

    }); 

</script>
```

I think the addEventListener isn't able to recognize the player.php file that's being loaded via ajax.

Comment: Instead of faking a user event, which is flaky at best, even when not using the outdated `onclick` attribute, simply call `loadurl()` directly.

Comment: Sure thanx for the tip! I did change it to what you suggested but still didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code you were using, I can see many errors:

- the `<source>` tag should self close;
- the `<source>` tag should be a child of `<audio>` tag
- tha `<audio>` tag must not have the `loop` attribute, or the `ended` event is never called; you have to remove this attribute even from the player.php script.

I think you have already removed the `loop` attribute from the actual code, otherwise it shall not work even on the first time.

Now, the problem occurrs because of this line:

```
document.getElementById(targetID).innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
```

because you are deleting the current audio object and replacing it with a new one.
When the track ends it raise the `ended` event on the new audio object, which has no event handler attached. The event handler you defined earlier wouldn't be called anymore.

The proper way to do things is to not replace the audio object, but simply replace its `src` attribute with the new track name.

**Edit**

So you could change your player.php to return the file name and other data without the html tags, for example in json format:

```
$track = array('file'=>$file, 'image'=>$image);
echo json_encode($track);
```

and replace the above line with:

```
var track = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText);
audio.src = track.file;
document.querySelector('#image').src = track.image;
document.querySelector('#download').href = track.file;
```

where `image` and `download` are the IDs of the `<img/>` and `<a>download</a>` elements.

Another options is to rebind the `ended` event each time you replace the html, but I strongly discourage this approach. Anyway, if you choose to follow this path, you must do it this way:

```
function loadurl(dest, targetID) {
    ...
    document.getElementById(targetID).innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
    var audio = document.querySelector('#myAudio');
    audio.addEventListener("ended", () => {
        loadurl.call(this,'player.php?random=1','player');
    });
    ...
}

var audio = document.querySelector('#myAudio');
audio.addEventListener("ended", () => {
    loadurl.call(this,'player.php?random=1','player');
});
```

Please note that the `audio` symbol must be variable, not constant, otherwise you can't replace its value with the new audio element.

Comment: I could do but it's not only the audio that's changed but also the image associated with the image is also changed, plus the download link as well, hence why I needed to change the whole div? And you right, I did remove the loop from the website. Forgot to change it on here.

Comment: @JaySmoke I have update the answer to handle your last requirement.

Comment: I think am gearing towards the first approach using json. But I am confused as to were to put what. Initially you said the problem was the document.getElementById(targetID) and you said to replace it. So am I to replace that line with the var track or am suppose to keep it and replace the div content inside player.php with the var track function?

Comment: In player.php you have to add the lines `$track = array('file'=>$file, 'image'=>$image);
echo json_encode($track);` and remove all html output. In the js function you have to remove the original line (`document.getElementById(targetID).innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;`) and replace it with `var track = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText);
audio.src = track.file;
document.querySelector('#image').src = track.image;
document.querySelector('#download').href = track.file;`.

Comment: Getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange (<anonymous>:19:21)

Comment: The second option works fine, but you don't recommend it. What are the drawbacks to using this option? It actually does exactly what I need it to. I am able to interrupt playback and it would still pick up where it left off and continue playing. Something the json option couldn't do.

Comment: For the unexpected token error, navigate to the player.php and take a look at the output, probably you are getting some php error, or you forgot to remove some html output. For the second option I don't recommend it because replacing the whole html node to just change few attributes is an overkill, and if you aren't doing it for a valid reason you will easely incurr in errors like the one described before. Of course you are free to choose what you like more. Both will work.